# Probability distribution for the number of triangles containing the center of a circle

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry

Pick $n$ points randomly on a circle centered at the origin.  Let $X$ be the number of the ${n \choose 3}$ triangles with those vertices that contain the origin in their interior.  For fixed $n$, what is the probability distribution of $X$?

For $n=3$, we have $P(X=0)={3\over4}$ and $P(X=1)={1\over4}$.

For $n=4$, we have $P(X=0)=P(X=2)={1\over2}$.

For $n=5$, we have $P(X=0)=P(X=3)=P(X=4)={5\over16}$ and $P(X=5)={1\over16}$.

If we multiply these fractions by $2^{n-1}$, then the numbers form this "triangular" pattern:

3 1

4 0 4

5 0 0 5 5 1

6 0 0 0 6 0 12 0 8

7 0 0 0 0 7 0 0 14 7 0 7 14 7 1

8 0 0 0 0 0 8 0 0 0 16 0 16 0 8 0 24 0 32 0 16

9 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 0 0 0 0 18 0 0 18 9 9 0 0 27 9 0 27 36 9 9 30 27 9 1

What is going on here?  Is there a closed form or recursive formula for these probabilities?  There are some intriguing patterns here, but I can't prove most of them.

Comment: How did you compute these values?

Comment: It is not hard to calculate the probabilities for n=3 and n=4 from first principles.  The probabilities for n=5 take a little more work, but can be done with some calculus.  For larger n, i used Monte Carlo simulation.

Comment: You are multiplying the probabilities by $2^{n-1}$.

Comment: An idea (going back to Wendel) that may help here.  We can view our points as generated as follows: Choose $n$ random points $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ from the upper half circle, and let $a_{n+1}, a_{n+2} \dots, a_{2n}$ be the diametrically opposite points to those points.  We can view our points as coming from independently choosing to include either $a_j$ or $a_{n+j}$ for each $j$.  The key point here: a triangle contains the center of the circle exactly when the three vertices are in the same half-circle, and that event doesn't depend on what the $a_j$ are... (continued next comment)

Comment: ...only on which of $\{j, n+j\}$ is chosen for each $j$.  This explains why your probabilities all can be written as fractions with denominator $2^{n-1}$ (WLOG you can assume $a_1$ is chosen, and there's $2^{n-1}$ choices for the other $j$), and may help in terms of computing the sequence for larger $n$.

Comment: From the table for each n the largest value of k in which P(Xn=k) is non-zero is {1,2,5,8,14,20,30}. This matches A006918 in OEIS after a shift index. This gives evidence the distribution depends on if n is even or odd. In fact, from table if n odd we have 1 at the end and for n even we have 2^(n/2). Another bit of evidence.

Comment: E[Xn] = (1/4) (n choose 3) and Var[Xn] = (1/4) n E[Xn]

Answer (score 3):

Denote $X$ by $X_n$. The first pattern suggested by the data  is  $$P(X_n=0)=n/2^{n-1}\,.$$
To prove this, note that if $X_n=0$, then the sampled points $y_1,\ldots,y_n$  lie on a half circle. There are $n$ possibilities for the first point $y_i$ (clockwise) in the occupied half circle, and once it is chosen,  the other $n-1$ points $\{y_j: j \ne i\}$ must fall in the half-circle clockwise from $y_i$.